# LaTeX doesn't update BiBTeX references

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texworks

I am trying to write a paper, so I need to cite references. I use TexWorks as the LaTeX editor and BibTeX for these references. Now, I have problems when I update the BibTeX database, where it only shows one of the references whenever I cite it, but not the other ! Even worse, when I delete the `\autocite` of this ref, it still shows me the reference in the bibliography section, updates it if I change for example the autor name, but there is no part in the paper that cites it anymore. And the other references are unknown to LaTeX (it shows them as bold)...

I tried a lot of different solutions that I have found here and there :

- Deleting the cache folder and then compile in the order `Latex -> bibtex -> Latex`. It doesn't change anything.
- Checking the `.blg` file to see if there are warnings, there are none.
- Deleting the `.aux` file and recompile everything.

Here is the LaTeX file :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{report}

Blah blah blah.
\autocite{foobar} \autocite{foo} \autocite{bar}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Knowing that both files `.tex` and `.bib` have the same name.

And the BibTeX one :

```
@book{foo,
  author = {aaa and bbb},
  title = {{First}},
  year = {2004},
}
@article{bar,
  author = {Mark},
  title = {{Second}},
  year = {2020},
}
@inproceedings{foobar,
  author = {Someone},
  title = {{Third}},
  year = {2020},
}
```

Comment: did you run latex _twice_ after running bibtex?

Comment: As David says, if you're u cite something new, then the mantra is latex, bibtex, latex, latex. Only at the alst latex run is the new `\cite` data available. If you've just updated a title of an entry you've already cited, bibtex, latex is enough. Additionally, I would not recommend using double braces on all the title entries

Comment: It sounds like you employ the `biblatex` package. If so, with which options do you load `biblatex`? Does your document feature an `\addbibliography` directive? Do you run bibtex or biber to create the formatted bibliography?

Comment: The commands you use suggest you load `biblatex`. With `biblatex` you usually need to run Biber instead of BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on doing that with your editor.

Comment: Also relevant https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to make it work. The problem was that I compiled my `.tex` with [image: pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex] and the `.bib` with [image: BibTex].

The solution was to compile the former only with [image: pdfLaTeX] (1) and the latter with [image: Biber] (2), with the known order :

(1) -> (2) -> (1) ( -> (1) ).

Then we can compile again with the first picture, to have MakeIndex work on the pdf file resulting.